# Receiving Push Notification twice

Tags: java, android, push-notification

> I have integrated an api to send the push notification and I am receiving notification from that api itself. But then I wanted to add pending Intent on the notification so I have written below code

```
private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        notification_id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null && remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle() != null)
        {
            final int NOTIFY_ID = 1002;
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            String type = remoteMessage.getData().get("type");
            String name = "my_package_channel";
            String id = "my_package_channel_1"; // The user-visible name of the channel.
            String description = "my_package_first_channel"; // The user-visible description of the channel.
            Intent notificationIntent = null;
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

            //PENDING INTENT
            notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
            notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("isNotification", true);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            if (notifManager == null) {
                notifManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                NotificationChannel mChannel = notifManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
                if (mChannel == null) {
                    mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
                    mChannel.setDescription(description);
                    mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                    mChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
                    mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                    notifManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                }
                builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id);
                builder.setContentTitle(title)  // required
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eyeplus_logo) // required
                        .setContentText(body)  // required
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setTicker(title)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            } else {
                builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                builder.setContentTitle(title)                           // required
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eyeplus_logo) // required
                        .setContentText(body)  // required
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setTicker(title)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400})
                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
            }

            Notification notification = builder.build();
            notifManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
        }
```

> After this I am receiving notification twice. What can should I do to resolve this?
>
> Thanks in Advance

Comment: pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
 change this line

Comment: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

Comment: Shall I write this? pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Comment: Shall I write this?

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Comment: this line PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT You can change after ur problem slove

Comment: pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: If I keep FLAG_ONE+SHOT only then my pending intent doesn't work

Comment: My pending Intent doesn't work with FLAG_ONE_SHOT or FLAG_ONE_SHOT | FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: I think after adding this notification plate is receiving api notification only

Comment: yes Api Notification u will get